# Sheet Music Software, w/ Measures/Bars per System Setting

Tags: notation, sheet-music, software, engraving

For many years I was an "Encore" user, and alas, Encore is no longer supported. (Rumors of a new version persist, but... we'll see....)  I used it to create piano sheet music.

Encore allowed the user to specify measures/bars per system, and that could vary throughout the song.  Is there any music notation software out there that offers that feature?  I found that flexibility with that setting made for "reader-friendly" arrangements.

Comment: Musescore allows you to rig the number of measures in each system with the proper break-spacer-dividers (I never did quite figure out what they were called). Does this count?

Comment: Specifying the number of bars per system is a basic feature of any modern professional notation program.

Comment: In Sibelius, if you're not satisfied with the generated system breaks, it's as easy as selecting a bar line and pressing Enter, as if you're entering a hard line end in a piece of text. I'm sure Sibelius is not unique in that respect.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know all the current music writing programs *) supports you selecting the number of bars per system. The exact way to do it, more or less automatic varies between the programs but it can always be done.

*) Includes but not limited to Dorico, Sibelius, Finale, MuseScore

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of any modern notation program that DOESN'T let you choose where line breaks come, either by an overall 'x bars per line' setting (sometimes you WANT a fixed 4 bars on each line) or by manually entering line breaks.

Obviously if you want a different number of bars on each line you can't command this with a single setting!

But your question is a non-problem.  Different programs may set line breaks in a different way to however Encore did it.  But they all let you do it.